# SharePoint list column formatting schema do not resolve

Tags: list, sharepoint-online

I have the following column formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase(@currentField),'07') != -1, 'ms-fontColor-redDark','')"
  }
}
```

The first line give the following error:
`$ref '/properties/attributes/class' in 'https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json' can not be resolved.(768)`.

Replacing the schema link to `https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json` throw the same error.

The list did work properly last week, and with no changes to formatting I get this error and I have no idea on how to troubleshoot this.

Edit: I can open the JSON links in my browser and from what I can tell it looks OK.

Comment: You may give a try on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying in SP 2019 , Excel-style expressions are not supported on SP 2019. Here is the article I found. Could you please refer this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/423002/sharepoint-json-column-formatting-not-working.html